# Using fill_between for a band

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been using `fill_between` to fill between the two red lines as seen in the image. I've been using [this example](http://matplotlib.org/users/recipes.html) (3rd figure from bottom).

However, in my case, I have two x values for one y value. I have nearly got it but do not understand what is going wrong here:

```
ax = plt.subplot(111)
plt.ylim(0.1, 1.2)
plt.xlim(0.03, 5.0)
ax.fill_between(inner_edge, outer_edge, mass, facecolor='b')
plt.loglog(inner_edge, mass, 'r-')
plt.loglog(outer_edge, mass, 'r-')
```

Why is the program filling just part of it. And what's that twisting?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`fill_betweenx`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.fill_betweenx) instead

```
ax.fill_betweenx(mass, inner_edge, outer_edge, facecolor='b')
```

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

inner_edge = np.linspace(0.1, 5.0, 10)
outer_edge = inner_edge * 0.3
mass = np.linspace(0.1, 1.2, 10)

ax = plt.subplot(111)
plt.ylim(0.1, 1.2)
plt.xlim(0.03, 5.0)

ax.fill_betweenx(mass, inner_edge, outer_edge, facecolor='b')

plt.loglog(inner_edge, mass, 'r-')
plt.loglog(outer_edge, mass, 'r-')

plt.show()
```

[image]